# How to attach Cycrypt or gdb before a program start

Tags: ios, gdb, penetration-testing, cycript

I am in the middle of PT where application is checking for JailBreak, sooner it starts and the first screen user see is Alert that application is Jailbroken and click okay to exit.

My question: Is there a way to attach Cycript before application starts or start application with Cycript as it seems very late to change method when it is already called by application and I am on the close alert.

Please advise.

or advise If I can run application with GDB, rather than attaching with the process later -- same issue here, it is too late to attach to gdp after running the application  because decision of JailBroken is already done.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/bypassing-jailbroken-checks-in-ios.html) which explains in detail about run time modifications using gdb as well as with cycript.

May be helpful for you or someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered same question and I got over that by using `choose()` in cycript and function `-[UIModalView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:]`

1. Use `choose(UIAlertView)` to search all `AlertView`
2. Try figure out which one is your target and call `[choose(UIAlertView)[i] dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:0]`

   *i is the sequence you get in step 1